# Cloud Firestore not returning all documents requested

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore to store several thousand documents each containing a field called "Best score". For most of the documents, "Best score" is a String but a number of them take a Long value (I'm in the process of deleting the ones with String values). The problem I'm seeing is that when I query the database, only two documents are returned (one for a document named "initial" that I deleted and the other is the document for my test device). I'm not using any authentication; the app uses the device identifier to keep track of the document:

```
// Get user's device ID and use it to locate user document. If none, create 
     one.
   androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

The database looks like this:

[image]

and here are the current rules for the database:
[image]
Here is the code that queries the database:

```
private static final String FSBESTSCORE = "Best score";
private static final String DEVICEIDS = "deviceIDs";

baseRef = db.collection(DEVICEIDS);

spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Query firstQuery = baseRef.orderBy(FSBESTSCORE, Query.Direction.ASCENDING).whereNotEqualTo(FSBESTSCORE, "").limit(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);
registration = firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }
 }
```

Thinking that caching might be the culprit, I modified my code as follows:

```
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Query firstQuery = baseRef.orderBy(FSBESTSCORE, Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .whereNotEqualTo(FSBESTSCORE, "")
            .limit(MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);

    firstQuery.get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();
                if (querySnapshot != null && !querySnapshot.isEmpty()) {
    }
```

In this case, I get a permissions error, which is odd since I gave read access to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of **read** operations in security rules:

- `get`, which is for reading a single document
- `list`, which is checked when you read a range of documents

Since your code executes a query, the rules engine looks for a matching `list` rule. Since you don't have a `list` rule, it rejects the read operation.

You can either add a `list` rule to your existing `get` rule, or use `read` instead of `get` (`read` = `get` + `list`).

Also see the Firebase documentation on [granular security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Comment: Holy Smoke! Frank, YOU DA MAN! At first I thought your suggestion didn't help because I was still seeing only 2 documents after several minutes. But now, the next day, I'm seeing all 10 (CHUNK_SIZE). I've since updated CHUNK_SIZE to 100, since I only want to post the Top 100 scores. I'm not sure how long it will take before I'll see more than 10 scores (there are 43 total currently).